# How do I retrieve twitter xml for Flash site via php properly

Tags: php, actionscript-3, curl, twitter

Am I using TwitterScript to retrieve Twitter data for inside a Flash site. Due to Twitter's crossdomain policy, I need to setup a php proxy...
Firstly I made a simple one

```
<?php 
$url = $_GET['url'];
readfile($url);
?>
```

but I then get this error

```
URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration
```

which is only resolved by getting my host to turn fopen() on, which I don't want to do.

Then I found this

```
<?php

function get_content($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

ob_start();

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$string = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

return $string;    
}

#usage:
$url = $_GET['url'];
$content = get_content ($url);
var_dump ($content);
?>
```

which solves that problem but the data now is the correct XML but looks like:

```
string(39950) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statuses type="array">
<status>
...
</statuses>"
```

How do I get the XML data out of that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using var_dump() when you want to output the result. Just use `echo` instead. Also you don't need output buffering to get the content of the site.

Fixed Code

```
<?php

function get_content($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$string = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

return $string;    
}

#usage:
$url = $_GET['url'];
$content = get_content ($url);
echo $content;
?>
```